# How can I conveniently bind Response.errors to errorText label in the TextFormField widget(Input Decoration)

Tags: api, http, flutter

## Variable

```
Map <String, dynamic> customerFormErrors;

# Widget
TextFormField(
 keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
 decoration: InputDecoration(
     labelText: 'Customer Email',
     errorText: '${customerFormErrors.email}',
     border: OutlineInputBorder(),
     fillColor: mainColor,
     prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.email),
    ),
onSaved: (value) {
     this.customer.email = value;
},
),
);

# Submit Function
  _submitForm(Customer customer) async {


      Create a Customer 
    */

    Response response = await createCustomer(this.customer);
    if (response.statusCode == 201 || response.statusCode == 200) {

      // Customer has been added

      Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(
          SnackBar(backgroundColor: mainColor, content: Text('Added')));
    } else {

      // Notify him with errors

      setState(() {
        customerFormErrors = jsonDecode(response.body);
      });
    }
  }
```

I am posting to an API and then attaching the error response body to a variable.
is there a way to bind that variable to errorText of TextFormField.

Somewhat like angular, where we use typesafe operator like the following {{ error?.name }} ?

I posted it here: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/40254

Comment: Maybe you should use a variable instead of string interpolation in `errorText`.

Comment: For large forms, wouldn't it become tedious?

Comment: Yes it can be tedious, however I think this is the way to do with Flutter state managment (not 100% sure)